# Git: doesn't add filename with dash

Tags: git

lastest git versin on archlinux that doesn't add filename that contain dash, e.g: `test-abc` (`git version 2.19.2`)

How to automatically add filename with dash (or folder) with git?

Comment: What is the error you get when trying to do this?

Comment: There's no error, it just doesn't appear in repo for no reason.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file that matches these files with a pattern?

Comment: I can asure that, non-dash filename in the same folder can be added to repo but dash name doesn't, I might doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: Steps to produce: I blindly apply these steps to force apply rules in modified .gitignore https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757964/5813693 and it removed all my files in cached, but still keep local, then I removed .git folder but .gitignore has weird behaviror right after doing that. I tried to apply logic of exlucde all folders/subfolders then include them later at that time, didn't work well as mentioned in the 1st post that dash filename didn't work for none reason.

Comment: I reverted back to normal logic, include all and then do filter on specific folder that need to exclude something, then it work again. Then while writing this comment, I realize that `test-abc` here is a folder, I need an extra exlude more lke in this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485633/256195